# Bluetooth transmitter function working on an Android device

Tags: bluetooth-audio

I have a Bluetooth transmitter and receiver, and would like to get the transmitter function working on an Android device, with the idea being an audio input into the transmitter end gets output on the device end wirelessly.

The manual of that device shows that the TX works under something called SBC and aptX.
Is there a way to have an android device be considered as SBC, aptX, or its variants?

[image]

Comment: SBC and aptX are just names of audio codecs. SBC is the standard Bluetooth audio codec supported by all Android devices and aptX is a proprietary codec with better quepality supported by some Android devices. Your main problem is that usually Android only sends Bluetooth Audio. Not sure if an app can receive Bluetooth Audio traffic.